# What does the second 'intelligence' mean/imply in the sentence of "An intelligence organization that fears intelligence?”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, implication

My friend and I had another argument over the meaning/implication of **the second 'intelligence'** in the following sentence:

“An intelligence organization that fears **intelligence**?” Tony said. “That’s historically . . . not awesome.”

My friend believed that the second intelligence is the same as the first one –– **also means "spy"**, which refers to Tony's action of breaking into S.H.I.E.L.D.’s secure files by decryption program ever since he was on board, like a spy.

I believe the second one means "smartness/cleaverness", which refers to Tony's own high IQ, and **he is being sarcastic**, pointing out that SHIELD, an intelligence **organization , full of elites (intelligent persons),  should not have feared to bring one more intelligent person (himself) into the organization,** which leads to the conclusion that Fury is definitely hiding sth from people.

So, which one is correct? or we both wrong? And if , not necessarily, anyone could point out how to distinguish the two would be a lot more helpful, thanks a lot.

Here is the sentence in the context:

> Bruce sighed and took off his glasses. “‘A warm light for all
>   mankind,’” he quoted. “Loki’s jab at Fury about the cube.”
>
> “I heard it,” Cap said.
>
> “I think that was meant for you,” Bruce said to Tony. “Even if Barton
>   didn’t tell Loki about the tower, it was still all over the news.”
>
> “The Stark Tower? That big ugly . . .” Tony looked up. “Building?” Cap
>   finished. “In New York.”
>
> “It’s powered by an Arc Reactor, a self-sustaining energy source,”
>   Bruce pointed out. “That building will run itself for, what? A year?”
>
> “That’s just the prototype,” Tony said. “I’m kind of the only name in
>   clean energy right now,” he explained to Cap. “That’s what he’s
>   getting at.”
>
> Cap didn’t know what he meant by clean energy, but he could tell it
>   was another of Tony’s typical boasts, so he let it pass.
>
> “So why didn’t S.H.I.E.L.D. bring him in on the Tesseract project?”
>   Bruce asked. “What are they doing in the energy business in the first
>   place?
>
> “I should probably look into that once my decryption program finishes
>   breaking into all of S.H.I.E.L.D.’s secure files.” Tony looked at a
>   tiny computer tablet, barely bigger than a credit card.
>
> “I’m sorry,” Cap said. “Did you say—”
>
> “Jarvis has been running it since I hit the bridge,” Tony said. “In a
>   few hours, I’ll know every dirty secret S.H.I.E.L.D. has ever tried to
>   hide.”
>
> “Yet you’re confused about why they didn’t want you around,” Cap said.
>
> **“An intelligence organization that fears intelligence?”** Tony said.
>   “That’s historically . . . not awesome.”
>
> Cap felt his temper starting to rise. He got it under control.
>
> *The Avengers I*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a pun, or wordplay. It plays with the double meaning of "intelligence" meaning both "spies" and "cleverness".

The second "intelligence" basically means "cleverness", and, in context, it is probably Tony talking about himself.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, my initial thought was it's a pun:) so how's my friend answer? is it make sense to a native speaker?

Comment: It could be an aspect of the pun, but "an intelligence" doesn't mean "a spy".